# Vault missing client token

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I'm getting below error when trying to fetch secrets from Vault. Below is my deployment file. The vault server runs on another kubernetes cluster and I have installed vault agent on my cluster. When I execute below it shows the connection is established.

```
curl \              
    --request POST \
    --data @data.json \
    http://myvault.com/v1/auth/approle/login


---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-deployment
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-mysecret: 'secret/data/mysecret'
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: 'myrole'
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: web
      containers:
        - name: web
          image: alpine:latest
          args:
            ['sh', '-c', 'source /vault/secrets/config']
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
```

Error Code

```
      │ vault-agent-init 2022-07-19T07:19:53.689Z [INFO]  auth.handler: authenticating                                                                           │
        │ vault-agent-init 2022-07-19T07:19:53.874Z [ERROR] auth.handler: error authenticating:                                                                    │
        │ vault-agent-init   error=                                                                                                                                │
        │ vault-agent-init   | Error making API request.                                                                                                           │
        │ vault-agent-init   |                                                                                                                                     │
        │ vault-agent-init   | URL: PUT http://myvault.com/v1/auth/kubernetes/login                                                        │
        │ vault-agent-init   | Code: 400. Errors:                                                                                                                  │
        │ vault-agent-init   |                                                                                                                                     │
        │ vault-agent-init   | * missing client token                                                                                                              │
        │ vault-agent-init    backoff=4m4.81s
```

New Error

```
 vault-agent-init 2022-07-19T16:41:44.299Z [INFO]  auth.handler: authenticating                                                                           │
│ vault-agent-init 2022-07-19T16:41:44.299Z [ERROR] auth.handler: error getting path or data from method: error="no known role ID" backoff=1m13.07s
```

These are the annotations I use in the Deployment file

```
annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: 'myrole'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-vault-addr: 'https://myvaultaddress.com'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-type: 'approle'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-path: 'auth/kubernetes'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-config-role-id-file-path: '/vault/custom/role-id'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-config-secret-id-file-path: '/vault/custom/secret-id'
```

Comment: If you are using AppRole auth instead of Kubernetes for the authentication engine for the Vault agent, then it needs a corresponding ConfigMap that configures the agent for AppRole usage.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Now I'm getting a new error. I have added it above

Comment: Please refer to the answer provided by @Container-Man in this [stackoverflow link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73050299/no-known-roleid-vault-agent)