# No known RoleID Vault Agent

Tags: kubernetes, vault

I'm using vault approle auth method to fetch secrets from vault. Below is my vault agent configmap.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  config-init.hcl: |
      "auto_auth" = {
        "method" = {
          "config" = {
            "role" = "test"
            "role_id_file_path" = "roleid"
            "secret_id_file_path" = "secretid"
            "remove_secret_id_file_after_reading" = false
          }
          "type" = "approle"
        }

        "sink" = {
          "config" = {
            "path" = "/home/vault/.token"
          }

          "type" = "file"
          "wrap_ttl" = "30m"
        }
      }

      "vault" = {
        "address" = "https://myvault.com"
      }

      "exit_after_auth" = true
      "pid_file" = "/home/vault/.pid"
```

Then I'm referencing the above configmap in the deployment file.

```
annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-configmap: 'my-configmap'
```

But I get below error

```
vault-agent-init 2022-07-20T10:43:13.306Z [ERROR] auth.handler: error getting path or data from method: error="no known role ID" backoff=4m51.03s
```

Comment: why don't you use kuberentes auth method? and assign it to serviceaccount ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a secret file in Kubernetes by using the RoleID and SecretID and pass the below annotation

```
vault.hashicorp.com/extra-secret: "secret-file"
```